# Spreading a table using Tidyr with multiple keys or values

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse, tidyr

I wish to spread a table. A picture is attached. I am trying to do so with spread using Tidyverse.

My attempt was:

```
Want = Have |> spread(key = Group, value = Number)
```

The result was poor, it kept me with 2 rows per time. Replacing the key or trying multiple values didn't work or ended with error. It has to be simple, how can it be done ?

[image]

Comment: Please make your examples reproducible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~Time, ~Group,   ~Name, ~Number,
        1,    "A",  "AKSJ",      12,
        1,    "B",   "ASJ",      13,
        2,    "A", "ISJKS",      12,
        2,    "B",   "EFJ",      45,
        3,    "A",    "IF",      12,
        3,    "B",    "DE",      54
)

df |> 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = Group,
    values_from = c(Name, Number),
    names_vary = "slowest"
  ) 
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>    Time Name_A Number_A Name_B Number_B
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 AKSJ         12 ASJ          13
#> 2     2 ISJKS        12 EFJ          45
#> 3     3 IF           12 DE           54
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is `names_vary = "slowest"` really needed? The result is the same if this is omitted...

Comment: For me the order of the columns changes if I omit it (I probably would not mind personally, but I wanted to reproduce the order as described in the original question).

Answer (score 0):

With base R we can try `reshape` like below to pivot the table wider

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "Time",
  timevar = "Group"
)
```

such that

```
  Time Name.A Number.A Name.B Number.B
1    1   AKSJ       12    ASJ       13
3    2  ISJKS       12    EFJ       45
5    3     IF       12     DE       54
```

## data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Time = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), Group = c("A", "B",
"A", "B", "A", "B"), Name = c("AKSJ", "ASJ", "ISJKS", "EFJ",
"IF", "DE"), Number = c(12, 13, 12, 45, 12, 54)), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```